# path not defined in d3 example

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Abject newbie to D3.  I'm starting with the working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7HZcR/3/
and am modifying to my purpose.  I got that exact code working in my own html, but as I'm tring to modify it, I'm running into the error

```
d3_test02.html:155 Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at _.tick (d3_test02.html:155)
    at _.t [as tick] (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at Object.l.tick [as c] (d3.v3.min.js:4)
    at Rn (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at Tn (d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

The code I'm using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>

    <style>
        path.link {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #666;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        marker#licensing {
          fill: green;
        }

        path.link.licensing {
          stroke: green;
        }

        path.link.resolved {
          stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
        }

        circle {
          fill: #ccc;
          stroke: #333;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        text {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
          pointer-events: none;
        }

        text.shadow {
          stroke: #fff;
          stroke-width: 3px;
          stroke-opacity: .8;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- This sets the size of the box you're working with and calls the script source, which is D3
    It also calls 2 scripts to help with saving the output -->


    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvg/1.5/canvg.min.js"></script>
    <script src="saveSvgAsPng.js"></script>


    <script>

        function makeGraph() {
            // Length of the running time in milliseconds //
            const simulationDurationInMs = 50000;
            whichMap = document.getElementById("ddlPrm").value + ".json";

            $("#svgGraph").empty(); // Clear out any existing graph

            // document.getElementById('svgGraph').style.display = "block";
            $("#b1").css('color', 'red')


            d3.json(whichMap, function (error, graph) {
                if (error) throw error;
                links = graph['links']
                nodes = graph['nodes']


            console.log(nodes)
            let startTime = Date.now()
            let endTime = startTime + simulationDurationInMs

            // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
            links.forEach(function (link) {
                link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = { name: link.source });
                link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = { name: link.target });
            });

            // Can I use the nodes from Python/JSON?
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            var w = 600,
                h = 600;

            var force = d3.layout.force()
                .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
                .links(links)
                .size([w, h])
                .linkDistance(60)
                .charge(-300)
                .on("tick", tick)
                .start();


            // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
            svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
                .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
              .enter().append("svg:marker")
                .attr("id", String)
                .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                .attr("refX", 15)
                .attr("refY", -1.5)
                .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                .attr("orient", "auto-start-reverse")
              .append("svg:path")
                .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

            var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
                .data(force.links())
              .enter().append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
                .attr("marker-start", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; })
                .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

            var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
                .data(force.nodes())
              .enter().append("svg:circle")
                .attr("r", 6)
                .call(force.drag);

            var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
                .data(force.nodes())
              .enter().append("svg:g");

            // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
            text.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("y", ".31em")
                .attr("class", "shadow")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

            text.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("y", ".31em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

                  });

        } // makeGraph()

        // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
        function tick() {
          path.attr("d", function(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = 75/d.linknum;  //linknum is defined above
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
          });

          circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });

          text.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });
        }
        


    function saveGraph4() {
        document.title = whichMap = document.getElementById("ddlProcessMap").value;
        window.print()
    }
    </script>

</head>
<html>
<body>
    <label for="ddlProcessMap"> Choose a process map:</label>
    <select name="process_map" id="ddlPRM">
      <option value="prm1">prm1</option>
      <option value="prm2">prm2</option>
      <option value="prm3">prm3</option>


    </select>

    <button id="b1" type="button" style="background-color: lightblue;" onclick="makeGraph();">Make Graph</button>
    <button id="b2" type="button" onclick="saveGraph4();">Save Image</button>
    <div id="svg-container">
        <svg id='svgGraph'
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xml:space="preserve" width="800" height="600">
        </svg>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
    <div id="png-container"></div>
</body>
```

I'm looking right at the code where it defines the path data - exactly as it does in the examples I started with.  Note my source data is defined in a file rather than in line. I have different fields - and I expect to debug those when I get to the point. But I can't get past this path problem.
I tried moving the tick function inside the d3.json()

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `path` variable isn't declared globally, but instead is declared in `makeGraph()`. Because it's declared in the "scope" of `makeGraph()`, `tick()` doesn't have access to it -- and thus you get the error `path is not defined`. (In the JSFiddle, path is declared globally.) So, you could just declare them outside of the function to start (just stick `var path;` at the top of your JS file, and then set it to the correct value in the `makeGraph` function), although there might be a better solution I don't know that's specific to D3.

It looks like once you fix that, you'll probably also get `circle is not defined` and `text is not defined` because they too are declared in `makeGraph` but then you try to use them in `tick()` -- so you'll have to globally declare them as well, if I'm reading your code right.

Comment: tx. I see what you mean, but I don't see how to fix it.  I tried putting var path; and var path{}; just after the <script> tag, tick sees path, but it's a different path. If I move the entire definition of path outside the d3.json(), then it can't read the input any more.  It needs to be able to read the data.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to move the entire definition out, just `var path;` at the top of the script tag. What do you mean, it's a different path? (I can also help you debug better if you link a sample JSON file for your code in your question.)

Comment: Sorry. I meant to mark this as the correct solution, but I've moved on to the next problem which surprisingly I understand, even if I'm not immediately sure how to fix it.